# How to prevent query string accessing attempts like /?hfsagrs=XXX

Tags: nginx, security

I am a new site owner and do not have so much traffic, but recently my NGINX access logs are flooded with requests as shown in this picture below.

I have attempted to block access with the pattern `\?.*` in the `location` block but it has no effect. How to block requests like this and return 444 ("blackhole" the requuest)?

[Nginx logs showing this scenerio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbCSj.png)

*For privacy reasons, IPs are redacted*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike apache rewrite rules both `location` and `rewrite` nginx directives works with so-called *normalized* URI (see the `location` directive [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to find out what does it mean) which does not include the query part. You can check the `$arg_hfsargs` nginx variable and close the connection if it isn't empty:

```
if ($arg_hfsargs) {
    return 444;
}
```

To close connection if the entire query string is not empty, you can check the `$args` variable instead.